# Case Statement off incoming Interface Param

Tags: c#

I'm trying to somehow determine based on my interface what type came in and then do some validation on that type.  Validation differes based on type that comes in.

```
  public static bool RequestIsValid(IPaymentRequest preAuthorizeRequest)
    {
        switch (preAuthorizeRequest)
        {
             case    
        }
    }
```

but either I can't do that with an interface or I'm not doing something that will make this work.

If I can't do that on an interface which looks like the probably because I think switch needs a concrete type, then how would I do this?  Just regular if statements that check typeof?

Is that the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just for completeness:**

You could also overload the method for the different implementations of IPaymentRequests and remove the one that takes the interface as parameter if you don't need a "default" handling. This is also safer because adding new implementations that apparently MIGHT require special handling do not default to something, but require another method with matching signature

```
public static bool RequestIsValid(PaymentRequestImplementation1 preAuthorizeRequest)
{
}

public static bool RequestIsValid(PaymentRequestImplementation2 preAuthorizeRequest)
{
}

...
```

If you really want to keep the method taking an IRequest you can also use reflection to call the more specific methods in case your caller casts your argument in an IRequest :

```
public static bool RequestIsValid(IRequest preAuthorizeRequest)
{
    var member = typeof (YourType).GetMethod(
        "RequestIsValid",
        BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public,
        null,
        new [] {preAuthorizeRequest.GetType()},
        null);

    if (member.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType != typeof (IRequest))
    {
        member.Invoke(null, new[] {Convert.ChangeType(preAuthorizeRequest, preAuthorizeRequest.GetType())});
    }

    // default
}
```

Comment: I thought this was the cleanest...so going with this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) or [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) like this:

```
public static bool RequestIsValid(IPaymentRequest preAuthorizeRequest)
{
    if (preAuthorizeRequest is PaymentRequestClassA)
    {
         var classA = (PaymentRequestClassA)preAuthorizeRequest;
         // handle PaymentRequestTypeA
    }
    else if (preAuthorizeRequest is PaymentRequestClassB)
    {
         var classA = (PaymentRequestClassB)preAuthorizeRequest;
         // handle PaymentRequestTypeB
    }
}
```

Or

```
public static bool RequestIsValid(IPaymentRequest preAuthorizeRequest)
{
    var classA = preAuthorizeRequest as PaymentRequestClassA;
    var classB = preAuthorizeRequest as PaymentRequestClassB;
    if (classA != null)
    {
         // handle PaymentRequestTypeA
    }
    else if (classB != null)
    {
         // handle PaymentRequestTypeB
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use `GetType` method and `typeof()`, but unfortunately you cannot use `switch`/`case` to make a decision:

> A switch expression or case label must be a `bool`, `char`, `string`, `integral`, `enum`, or corresponding nullable type.

You can use `if`/`else` statements or prepare `Dictionary<Type, Func<IPaymentRequest, bool>>` and use it to perform your validation logic.

```
private static Dictionary<Type, Func<IInterface, bool>> _validationFunctions
   = new Dictionary<Type, Func<IInterface, bool>>() {
       { typeof(ClassA), (input) => false },
       { typeof(ClassB), (input) => true }
   };

public static bool RequestIsValid(IInterface preAuthorizeRequest)
{
    return _validationFunctions[preAuthorizeRequest.GetType()](preAuthorizeRequest);
}
```

Comment: You could use `object.GetType().Name` in the switch.

Comment: but I'm evaluating an interface param, not an object

Comment: and I wouldn't want to base code on a name of an object, that's brittle